# Can not start new Intent activity from async function

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin, async-await

I have aproblem in a xamarin application for android.
from my main activity i call a login activity that checks if the user and passwordentered are correct ,it is done via Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices plugin.
i get the answer but when I try to open a new activity as intent in the async function that gets the result the app hangs.
i tried accessing that target activity from outside the async method and it works. my code :

```
private async Task<int> GetAdminUser(string userName,string password)
        {
            int userId = -1;

            try
            {
                users = await usersTable.Where (item => item.UserLoginName == userName && item.UserPassword == password).ToListAsync ();

                if(users != null)
                {
                    userId = users[0].UserId;
                }
                else{
                    userId = -1;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                userId = -1;
            }

            return userId;

        }

        private async Task GetAdminUserWrapper(string userName,string password)
        {
            int userId = await GetAdminUser (userName, password);
            if (userId != -1) 
            {
                //new AlertDialog.Builder (this).SetMessage ("User id : " + userId.ToString ()).Create().Show();
                await OpenUserBusinessSalesIntent (userId);
            }
        }

        async Task OpenUserBusinessSalesIntent (int userId)
        {
            try {
                Intent testActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(TestActivity));
                //userSalesActivity.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                //userSalesActivity.PutExtra ("UserIdBusiness",userId.ToString ());
                //SetResult (Result.Ok,testActivity);
                StartActivity (testActivity);
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {

            }
        }
```

Any help would be appriciated
Shlomy

Comment: Which one of the methods hang? And it is really difficult to understand whats going on in your last method. Why is it marked `async` if you dont `await` anything?

Comment: Are you calling `Result` or `Wait` on any  `Task`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the activity on the UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(() => {
  Intent testActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(TestActivity));

  StartActivity (testActivity);
});
```

Comment: Activity is a UI component and should be run on the main UI-Thread. UI manipulation on a non UI thread can cause all kinds of problems including hanging/crashing your app

Comment: Shouldnt that make it throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your ideas , the crash was when i tries to start a new intent in the async function
after I got the userId.
The solution was to use RunOnUiThread and wrap it with try catch and inside the runOnUiThread
to Start the intent.
10x
Shlomy